# How to solve elasticsearch parse problem?

Tags: elasticsearch

We used elastic search when our server shot down also elasticsearch closed. When I research anything I get an error like below.Why does the error occur and how can I fix it?

```
<p>Type: Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception</p>
<p>Message: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:97] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:97] [bool] failed to parse field [must]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:97"}},"status":400}</p>
<p>Filename: elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 641</p>
```

Comment: provide the query, please.

Comment: @rabbitbr I'am newbie. How can I find query?

Comment: So, somewhere in your server, some code is issuing a search request to elasticsearch. This search request most likely has a syntax error, we need to see it to tell you what is wrong. And you need to find it to be able to fix it.